# Is right inverse function unique?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a map. Can there be two different $g, g'\colon B\to A$ such that $fg = id = fg'$? Or is a right inverse always unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple right inverse.

Take this basic exemple :

$f: \{1,2\} \to \{1\}$ defined by $f(1) = f(2) = 1$

Now, $g_1: \{1\} \to \{1,2\}$ defined by $g_1(1) = 1$ and $g_2: \{1\} \to \{1,2\}$ defined by $g_1(1) = 2$ are two different right inverses of $f$

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks, dude!

Answer (score 0):

In general, a right inverse is unique (if it exists) if and only if $f$ is a bijection.

If $f$ is not a bijection, and there exists a right inverse $g$, then $f$ is a surjection but $f$ is not an injection. So then there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $x ≠ y$ but $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $g_1$ and $g_2$ defined by $g_1 (f(x)) = x$, $g_2 (f(x)) = y$, and $g_1(z) = g_2(z) = g(z)$ otherwise, are different right inverses.